# Gaussian Elimination

Tags: ocaml

Is there a library that I can use for solving a set of linear equations using Gaussian Elimination?

Answer (score 3):

I have never used it, but [lacaml](http://www.ocaml.info/home/ocaml_sources.html#lacaml) is a binding for [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/), which is a linear algebra library.

Comment: lacaml works well; you just have to get used to working with FORTRAN-format bigarrays.